# Compile time template values deduction

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, compile-time

I have this template matrix struct (I provided a constructor which takes std::initializer_list):

```
template<int rows, int cols, typename scalar = float>
struct matrix;
```

with a product operator defined outside the matrix struct, like this:

```
template<int n, int m, int p, typename scalar>
matrix<n, m, scalar> operator*(const matrix<m, p, scalar>& left, const matrix<p, n, scalar>& left);
```

and then declared as a friend inside the struct. So if I instantiate two matrices:

```
matrix<2, 3> A = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
matrix<3, 2> B = { 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
```

and I want to create a matrix C = A * B, I have to write:

```
matrix<2, 2> C = A * B;
```

And that's fine, but is there a way to omit the <2, 2> template? I believe that it can be deducted at compile time (because auto works fine):

```
auto C = A * B; // no errors
```

I'd like to write just `matrix` instead of `auto`, is it possible?

Comment: I think unless you use virtual base, it would be impossible since the return type must have template parameters.

Comment: Why didn't you try it? If you did, what happened when you tried it?

Comment: @cqdjyy01234 even with a virtual base class this wouldn't be possible because it would need to be a pointer or reference.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Maybe he will return a smart pointer from the multiplication, and use typedef.

Comment: @cqdjyy01234 then he would be over-complicating his code and almost definitely creating a bottleneck with dynamic allocation.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Yeah, of course. I just propose the possibility.

Comment: @cqdjyy01234 Oh. Well, yeah; by all means haha. Wouldn't recommend it though.

Comment: `auto` *is* a form of compile-time type deduction.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot (if you don't have some non-template base matrix). `matrix` is not a type, it's template and you should specify template parameters. `auto` is simplest thing, that you can do. Or, instead of `auto` you can use `decltype`

```
decltype(A * B) C = A * B;
```